# setState in async function react native

Tags: react-native

I use Navigator component in my app, to render content of route i do http request with fetch to get data from server.

```
componentDidMount () {
    fetch(url).then((res) => {
         this.setState({data: res});
    });
}
```

Problem I have is that sometimes fetch closure fires when component that called it is no longer mounted so I keep getting error that i'm trying to update unmounted component. This happens if you move quickly between routes. Is there a way to terminate closure execution if component is dismounted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On mounting your component you should start `fetch` request which gives `Promise` and store it.

Then you can make this `Promise` a `CancelablePromise` and cancel the promise on unmounting the component.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) you can read how to make `CancelablePromise`.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
What I actually had in my closure was fetch, than sort of received data, and setState at and. This give me idea to break this on 3 promises so i can even skip sorting if component is already dismounted on second part.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the component is mounted before settings the state.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.isMounted = true;
    fetch(url).then((res) => {
        if(this.isMounted) {
            this.setState({this.data: res});
        }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isMounted = false;
}
```

Comment: Read the article linked in my answer. `isMounted` is antpattern.

Comment: Woah, never seen that before. Thanks for the link.